# MATE menu has nothing but "Places"

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate

My MATE Menu has nothing in it but places, In Mozo it says it has all the applications and categories but nothing is there. Can anyone help? also Mozo can't be run without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.mate.mate-menu plugins-list "['places', 'system_management', 'newpane', 'applications']"
```

That should restore the list of plugins that display in Mate Menu to the default.